# Python Selenium Array

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to check all check boxes in an array with selenium-webdriver. But I am struggling in finding the correct methods/functions, somehow this whole code is very confusing.

What i have are either one or multiple databoxes like this:

```
<div class="data_row">
<span id="checkbox_detail_ONE" class="checkbox_detail">
<input type="checkbox" value="dir://TEST" name="file_list" onclick="check_enable_btn()">
```

from where I want to check all checkboxes except the one named **checkbox_detail_ONE**

In python I tried this, but I guess its a misinterpretation of the `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='checkbox_detail']"):
    if "ONE" in i.text:
        print "Keep "
    else: 
        print "Delete"
        i.click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying out the individual bits of your code, they seem to work for the most part. Your problem is probably in the exclusion of the check_detail_ONE checkbox. i.text returns the text contained in the element, but from the code you have posted there is nothing that leads me to believe that checkbox will contain ONE in it's text. 
For your exclusion, you will want to use a selection that will specifically select this checkbox. Selenium supports selection by ID, so you could use the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_detail_ONE")
```

Or if you prefer to use an xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("@id='checkbox_detail_ONE'")
```

And if you really want to make sure it's a span:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='checkbox_detail_ONE']")
```

This would lead to the following code:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='checkbox_detail']"):
    if i == driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='checkbox_detail_ONE']"):
        print "Keep "
    else: 
        print "Delete"
```

Now, since we will be checking boxes, which are separate elements, we will need to 
compare the input elements instead of the span they are contained in. We can select those by using xpath's `/descendant::` feature, leading to the following final code:

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='checkbox_detail']/descendant::input"):
    if i == driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='checkbox_detail_ONE']/descendant::input"):
        pass # no action required
    else: 
        i.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all checkboxes except the "checkbox_detail_ONE" one in one go using an xpath:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'checkbox_detail' and @id != 'checkbox_detail_ONE']")
```

This would return you all `span` elements except the one having "checkbox_detail_ONE" name.

If you need to get the `input` elements from here, you can use `following-sibling`:

```
//span[@class = 'checkbox_detail' and @id != 'checkbox_detail_ONE']/following-sibling::input
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I didn't verify your solution since the other suggestion worked out for me. But I think it makes me understand xpath better.